# Selenium framework using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to find the element Data Access.

The HTML code behind this is:

```
<ul class="tabs left">
<li id="tabPersonalInformation" class="current first">
<li id="tabSystemAccess">
<li id="tabDataAccess">
<a href="#dataAccess">Data Access</a>
</li>
```

The C# code that I am using is:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var DataAccess = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText("Data Access")));
DataAccess.Click();
```

It is unable to find the field DataAccess. The exception that I am getting is:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: unknown error: Element is not >clickable at point (543, 15). Other element would >receive the click: ...

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly occurred in the chrome browser due to target element overlay with other element. Selenium always perform `click` on the center of the element so due to overlay of other element it could not be click, In this case you should try to click using `IJavaScriptExecutor` as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var DataAccess =    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.LinkText("Data Access")));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", DataAccess);
```

Hope it helps...:)